# How to know which architecture does a third static library(.a) support?

Tags: linux, static-libraries

I have some static libraries but I don't who which architecture(arm7,etc...) they support.
Does it have some linux command to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 3 tools which used to determine architecture of .a support, these are `file`, `lipo` and `otool`

Using `file`

```
% file library.a
```

Using `lipo`

```
% lipo -info library.a
```

Using `otool`

```
% otool -hv library.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that static library is test.a containing test.o, then exec following commands:

ar -x  test.a 
file  test.o

It will print something about CPU architechture, for example x86-64.  And you can know which architechture it supports.